# Posts and pages not getting published

Tags: posts, pages

I just installed a fresh version of 4.5 on my server.
But for some reason every page or post is getting the status "Scheduled", it won't go to Published.
Other sites on the same server works fine.

Already tried a reinstall(clean).

Someone has an solution?

Regards

Comment: Update: If i set the Publish a day sooner, it does publish it...
Serversettings perhaps?

Comment: Reinstallation doesn't work because `post_status` is stored in database. Change all posts with status `future` to `publish` in your database should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, also deleted the database and re-created uit, didn't solved it:( It says: Page scheduled for {createdtime} (09:32 in this case).

Comment: Did you make a clean installation? If you do a clean installation, there's only one **Sample Page** and one **Hello World!** post.

Comment: Yes, clean of 4.4 and 4.5. Indeed those posts are there. But i simply can't create any new ones... Well i can but the status is future then.

Comment: Fixed, changed timezone from Asmterdam to UTC(+1) and now it does work

Answer (score 0):

Its because you where ahead of time!

Answer (score -1):

changed timezone from Asmterdam to UTC(+1) and now it does work

Comment: -1, really? Why:')